# Infinite amount of conflicts on Git Extensions

Tags: git, repository, git-extensions

I have made several pushes into Git Extensions, another programer too. I have spent more than 10 hours resolving conflicts, but they never stop comming, ¿Is there something wrong with git Extensions?, ¿Should I use another program?, ¿Such high amount of conflicts is normal due to several pushes?, ¿What can I do?

Comment: Are they full-file conflicts? Or only sections of files are  affected?

Comment: Just parts of code, small in fact. Not a solution, but something that helped me was to create another branch... and I realized later that not doing git rebase develop before doing push was the mayor cause of the problem.